# Myetherwallet issue with retrieving Rep Tokens after Augur's Crowdsale

Tags: myetherwallet, augur

We're trying to retrieve our augur tokens purchased in the crowd sale.

The balance shows up on etherscan/ethplorer, but when we follow augur's instructions re myetherwallet, the balance is 0.

Augur has stopped replying to our emails.

Thanking everyone in advance.

John

Comment: John, did you solve that issue, or is it still active?

Answer (score 0):

If you can see your balance in etherscan that is fine. you no need to worry about myetehrwallet. Try with mist wallet. or try incognito mode myetherwallet.